# WooCommerce - Adding Custom Order Without No Product

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I am working on a website at the now for a cake shop, they have a huge list of cakes that have been imported to the site and that all works fine for putting through orders that happen in the shop / on the phone etc.

However, some customers will come in and ask for a custom cake order that isn't listed in the product range (ie; two tier disney cake).

How can the person in the shop setup a custom order with a note attached to the order without having to choose a product first?

Hope someone can help.